# Collapse error message into a single block when the error message is modified to print in red

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

How can I get a printed error message in RMarkdown to collapse into a single block when the error message itself was modified to print in red?

In this example `collapse = T` works as expected.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, collapse = TRUE)
```

```{r error=T}
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x * 10
X * 10
```
````

In this example, I modified the error message to be formatted in red (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348136)). But then it doesn't collapse with the rest:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, collapse = TRUE)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(error = function(x, options) {
  paste0("<pre style=\"color: red;\"><code>", x, "</code></pre>")
})
```

```{r error=T}
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x * 10
X * 10
```
````

I tried to specify `collapse = T` again in the specific code chunk but this won't work either:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, collapse = TRUE)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(error = function(x, options) {
  paste0("<pre style=\"color: red;\"><code>", x, "</code></pre>")
})
```

```{r error=T, collapse = T}
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x * 10
X * 10
```
````

Comment: This is tricky. HTML or pdf output?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer HTML would be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When knitting to HTML, the highlighting is done in the last step, when the site is generated. The collapsing of chunks is done prior to that.

What complicates this is the fact that errors are highlighted just like strings and cannot be distinguished from actual string output.

Adding classes by altering a hook (like ```` ```{.myClass} ...source code... ``` ````) does not help us, since this will break the chunk collapsing mechanism and even if I fix this (can be done by simply changing the underlying regex inside the chunk hook) the class is not present anymore when the site has rendered.

So in the end I only came up with the following.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".hljs-comment:contains('####')").css("color", "red");
    var tmp = $(".hljs-comment:contains('####')").text();
    $(".hljs-comment:contains('####')").text(tmp.replace("####", "##"));
  }, 15);
});
</script>



# Header 1

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, collapse = T)

default_hook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("error")
knitr::knit_hooks$set(error = function(x, options) {
  x <- paste0("##", x)
  default_hook(x, options)
})
```

```{r error=T}
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x * 10
X * 10
```
````

Here we change the error hook in that sense that two additional hashes are prepended to the output. In the Javascript snippet we then look for these lines, change the font color to red and delete the hashes again. This is done with a delay of 15ms. Why? If we execute the code immediately, the elements carrying the classes generated by highligh.js are not yet present. So we have to be a little slower.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With the current [development version of **knitr**](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) (`remotes::install_github('yihui/knitr')`), you can specify the [CSS class for error messages](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1676). Here is an example:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE)
```

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.red { 
  color: red;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  border-top-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```


```{r error=T, class.error='red'}
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x * 10
X * 10
```
````

Output:

[image: Custom class for errors in knitr]

Comment: Ah nice. Did not know yet. But collapsing the error does not work right. I mean It would be the same attempt when manually adding a class.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the original question. Then I don't have a better solution than the hack you mentioned (which is not totally robust but the action of collapsing is lossy so I guess you have to hack at it). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Yihui. As for the color this is indeed very nice. My question would be, can `class.error = ... ` be adapted to also specify for example the color of a function, or the color of the arguments of a function to something other than the default? Something like `class.function = ...`? Or should I maybe ask this as a new question?

Comment: I just provided an ugly CSS hack to make it look like the error had been collapsed into the previous code block. I don't quite understand your new question. Do you mean something like `class.error = your_own_function_that_returns_a_class()`? You can already do that.

Comment: Yes that also works nicely and is also quite easy to understand what you did. Never mind my question. I have just discovered syntax highlighting and themes!